# Using Session variables in fancybox

Tags: c#, asp.net, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have an simple implementation of fancybox2 that works.  When I run the app, the link looks fine when I hover on it (`http://localhost:53481/Add.aspx`), and opens the fancybox when I click on it.

```
<a class="popup" href="Add.aspx" title="Add a Value">New Code</a>
```

I'd like to try something like shown below, but it doesn't work.  When I run the app, the link is not well formed (shows only as `http://localhost:53481/`), and the error message I get when I click on the link is "The requested content cannot be loaded.  Please try again later".

```
<a class="popup" href="<%# Eval(Session["Type"].ToString(), "Add.aspx?Type={0}") %>" title="Add a Value">New Code</a>
```

I am setting the value in my page load, and have also tried setting during session start without success.

```
Session["Type"] = "1";
```

Essentially I am trying to embed a variable in the href so I can pass it on to the page that will load in the fancybox.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<a class="popup" href="Add.aspx?Type=<%: Server.URLEncode(Session["Type"]) %>" title="Add a Value">New Code</a>
```

`<%# Eval..%>` should only be used for data binding values within a Repeater or DataTable, etc. Use `<%: %>` to output to the page with HTML encoding.

Comment: FYI: While your answer appears plausible, it has appeared in the 'low quality posts' queue after being flagged for deletion. I suspect this is because it is a code only answer without explanation.

Comment: @OliverMatthews: Thanks, improved answer.

Comment: @SilverlightFox, thanks for the reply.  Server.URLEncode did not work, but System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode did :)  I am using VS2013, .NET 4.5.1.  Thanks for leading me down the right path.